# PrimeNg color picker overlay hidden behind dialog

Tags: primeng

I'm using PrimeNG color picker overlay inside a dialog.

```
<p-colorPicker [(ngModel)]="activity.color" name="color" appendTo="body"></p-colorPicker>
```

The problem is that picker is not showing and expands the dialog body adding the scrollbars. I want the colorpicker to overlay over the dialog.

Setting `appendTo="body"` works for calendar widget, but not color picker. Based on docs I experimented with various options like e.g. specifying template variable in dialog `<p-dialog #activityDialog ...` and referencing it in appendTo of colorpicker, but this is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

```
<p-dialog [contentStyle]="{'overflow':'visible'}">
</p-dialog>
```

this does it all and is documented already: [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog)

---

I got it to work by setting:

```
:host /deep/.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

in the css of the component containing the dialog.
Though `:host /deep/` is  [deprecated](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) by Angular